# Binding Data into a dynamically created textboxes in winforms using c#

Tags: c#

i Have initially 3 textboxes on my mainForm in a groupbox. when i press enter on any of the 3 textboxes, it dynamically creates another 3 textboxes and so on.. Code for creating dynamic textboxes is this :

```
private void createTextBoxes(GroupBox groupbox)
    {
        x = 6;
        y += 40;
        x1 = 223;
        y1 += 40;
        x2 = 440;
        y2 += 40;

        TextBox tbparticular = new TextBox();
        tbparticular.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(textBoxParticular_KeyDown);
        TextBox tbQty = new TextBox();
        tbQty.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(textBoxQty_KeyDown);
        TextBox tbRate = new TextBox();
        tbRate.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(textBoxRates_KeyDown);


        tbparticular.Size = new Size(207, 20);
        tbQty.Size = new Size(207, 20);
        tbRate.Size = new Size(207, 20);

        tbparticular.Location = new Point(x, y);
        tbQty.Location = new Point(x1, y1);
        tbRate.Location = new Point(x2, y2);

        groupbox.Controls.Add(tbparticular);
        groupbox.Controls.Add(tbQty);
        groupbox.Controls.Add(tbRate);
        groupbox.Height += 20;
        //Particularpanel.Height += 20;
        //Form1.height
    }
private void textBoxParticular_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            createTextBoxes(this.groupBoxProperties);
        }
    }
private void textBoxRates_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            createTextBoxes(this.groupBoxProperties);
        }
    }
private void textBoxQty_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            createTextBoxes(this.groupBoxProperties);
        }
    }
```

Now, when the textboxes are created, i want to INSERT a record in a table. **My Question is How do i perform insert operation on the dynamically created texboxes each time.** Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If I have correctly understood the question, you can not access elements outside of the method.

You should use some global array like

```
TextBox[] tbparticular = ...
```

So then you can do all what you want with this element.

```
tbparticular[34].Text = "some text";
```

You can read all data in DB like

```
foreach(TextBox t in tbparticular)
{
    AddToDB(t.text)
}
```

Comment: well, i dont want to hard code the values.. i want to query the values and send it to database. Will this Method of your will work in this case?

Comment: Yep, You will have array of your texBoxes

Comment: foreach(TextBox t in tbparticular)
{
    AddToDB(t.text)
}